# PostgreSQL combine tables and filter two tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and trying to figure out a way to filter/combine two tables and then filter the results with a list of users.

I have two tables:

Table: `mi_user`

```
device_uuid   display_name
     1           Mike
     2           John
     3           Kate
     4           Bob
```

Table: `mi_device`

```
device_uuid   Status
     1        RETIRED
     2        ACTIVE
     3        VERIFED
     4        ACTIVE
```

I want to be able to take the two tables and do a query and pull a list of all users that are ACTIVE.  Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   mi_user u
JOIN   mi_device d USING (device_uuid)
WHERE  d.status = 'ACTIVE';
```

[Read about basic queries in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries.html)

Only returning columns of `mi_user` since you requested the `list of all users`.

Your table design doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense, though. Typically you would have a `user_id` in the user table and a user could have 0-n or 1-n devices, so you would have `user_id` in the device table as foreign key.

And the status of a device (like you have it) does really indicate that the user is "active"? Not the device?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Erwin.  What i'm trying to do is pull only the active device and see which user they are associated.  Table1 (mi_device) only has devices and all thing related to the device.  While table2 (mi-user) has info only for the user.  The command you provided seem to pull the correct number of items (42), all i get is the date that it last synced but user.  is there a way to pull the display_name or email_address associated with status that is Acitve?

Comment: @Sur-Inder: I put `u.*` in the `SELECT` list, meaning "all columns of table `mi_iser` - since `u` has been declared table alias in the `FROM` line. You can make that `SELECT *` to select *all* columns or list the column you want explicitly. But, please, start by reading the manual for the basics.

Comment: Thanks for you help Erwin.  I believe i was able to get this to work.  below is what i modified to your code:                                             SELECT device_uuid, display_name
FROM   mi_user u
JOIN   mi_device d USING (device_uuid)
WHERE  d.status = 'ACTIVE';